# Write Urdu with LuaTex

Tags: arabic

I figured out how to write with Arabic fonts

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\begin{document}
    My arabic test
    \arb{تحميل كيبورد عربي للكمبيوتر}
\end{document}
```

According to the documentation of `arabluatex` it *only* support arabic fonts. In chapter 1.1. it refers to `arabtex` and `arabxetex` for writing in Urdu or Pashto. Since I'm using lualatex I have some troubles. I didn't find proper samples how typeset with these fonts.

I do **NOT** need to have a transcript latin letter into the lang - preferably I need to switch it off. I *only* (?) need to display the input with the proper fonts - and most preferable with the proper typesettings. Is there a sample in which Arabic, Urdu, Pashto or/and Dairi are mixed together and are compilable with `lualatex` (1.10)

Comment: I have no idea what is the difference between the scripts, but probably you should switch to texlive 2020 so that you can use the new lualatex based on luahbtex 1.12 and so use the harfbuzz renderer.

Comment: About the switching to luatex1.12 I am heavily confused. On the offical luatex web site I find for download for Linux only a release from 2019. On Wikipedia I see there should be a stale release from March15th, 2020. But don't know from where to take it. And even if I would use 1.12 I'm still highly unclear how to use it. Do I still need the `arabluatex` or is it not any longer required?

Comment: luahbtex1.12 is part of texlive 2020 which will be released soon and can be pretested here https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html. But actually I wrote nonsense: you can try harfbuzz mode in texlive 2019 by using lualatex-dev instead of lualatex. see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520183/2388

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This here should probably work (to really make use of the HarfBuzz Render you need either texlive 2020 or should use the lualatex-dev format):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ur,mapdigits]{urdu}
\babelfont[urdu]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Amiri}


\begin{document}
My urdu test

\selectlanguage{urdu}

    یہ ایک جملہ ہے

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds great. Which means that I just need to set before the Urdu, Pashto or Arabic the specific language - so the `lualatex` uses the proper font, right? BTW: What means `mapdigits` since I didn't find it in the babel docu 3.29?

Comment: mapdigits in new in version 3.30 and it map numbers to the numbers of the script (but I have no idea if this is sensible here as I don't know the script. I copied this from another answer)

Comment: A followup to this answer could be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572932/48642